# Zsh git filename completion with "--git-dir=... --work-tree=...": not a git repository

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

I track my dotfiles using this method:

- A bare repository resides in `$HOME/repos/dotfiles`.
- All my dotfiles reside in their normal location, e.g. `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`, not `$HOME/repos/dotfiles/vimrc`.
- I run `git --git-dir=$HOME/repos/dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME ...` to manage things.

(Actually, I have a function `g()` that expands to the above command when I'm in `$HOME`, and to just `git` otherwise.)

Everything works great, except...

**The problem:** Zsh git filename completion doesn't work.

**Example:**

```
% pwd
/home/brian
% g status                                                                                                                                         ~
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .vim/vimrc
        modified:   .xmonad/xmonad.hs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
% g add <Tab>
Completing not a git repository
```

(The "Completing ..." stuff is due to `zstyle ':completion:*' format $'%{\e[0;31m%}Completing %B%d%b%{\e[0m%}'`.)

Notably, it would not suffice to somehow tell zsh's git completion to "move to/follow" the given value of `--work-tree`, as if `git` were being called from that directory, because explicitly doing that doesn't work either:

```
% cd repos/dotfiles
% g status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
% g add <Tab>
Completing not a git repository
```

**The question:** Is there an easy way to get extend zsh's git completion to this kind of a case?

Comment: This is a great question -- exactly the same problem I'm having nearly 3 years later... The below answers don't seem to be working for me... Did you ever get any joy with this one?

Comment: No, I ended up switching to [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/). Under this method, all of my *actual* dotfiles live in `~/repos/dotfiles`, organized into various top-level directories, and then I use `stow` to create symlinks of the dotfiles to their appropriate location (determined by the subdirectory structure of each top-level directory). It's not as simple as my original method, but (i) the dotfiles directory is a normal git repo, so zsh completion works perfectly, and (ii) I can also store configurations for things beyond just home directory dotfiles, e.g. stuff in `/etc`.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, its a bug in `zsh` completion for git. You can find discussion on 'zsh' mailing list [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg01186.html).

Daniel Shahaf did provided a patch for '_git':

```
diff --git a/Completion/Unix/Command/_git b/Completion/Unix/Command/_git
index 518e6d198..45a0fa622 100644
--- a/Completion/Unix/Command/_git
+++ b/Completion/Unix/Command/_git
@@ -6609,20 +6609,33 @@ __git_files_relative () {
 (( $+functions[__git_files] )) ||
 __git_files () {
   local compadd_opts opts tag description gitcdup gitprefix files expl
+  local pref

   zparseopts -D -E -a compadd_opts V: J: 1 2 n f X: M: P: S: r: R: q F:
   zparseopts -D -E -a opts -- -cached -deleted -modified -others -ignored -unmerged -killed x+: --exclude+:
   tag=$1 description=$2; shift 2

-  gitcdup=$(_call_program gitcdup git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>/dev/null)
-  __git_command_successful $pipestatus || return 1
+  case $(_call_program gitinworktree git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null) in
+    (true)
+      gitcdup=$(_call_program gitcdup git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>/dev/null)
+      __git_command_successful $pipestatus || return 1

-  gitprefix=$(_call_program gitprefix git rev-parse --show-prefix 2>/dev/null)
-  __git_command_successful $pipestatus || return 1
+      gitprefix=$(_call_program gitprefix git rev-parse --show-prefix 2>/dev/null)
+      __git_command_successful $pipestatus || return 1
+
+      local pref=$gitcdup$gitprefix$PREFIX
+      ;;
+    (false)
+      local pref=
+      ;;
+    (*)
+      # XXX what to do?
+      return 1
+      ;;
+  esac

   # TODO: --directory should probably be added to $opts when --others is given.

-  local pref=$gitcdup$gitprefix$PREFIX

   # First allow ls-files to pattern-match in case of remote repository
   files=(${(0)"$(_call_program files git ls-files -z --exclude-standard ${(q)opts} -- ${(q)${pref:+$pref\\\*}} 2>/dev/null)"})
@@ -7585,7 +7598,8 @@ _git() {
         ;;
       (option-or-argument)
         curcontext=${curcontext%:*:*}:git-$words[1]:
-       (( $+opt_args[--git-dir] )) && local -x GIT_DIR=$opt_args[--git-dir]
+        (( $+opt_args[--git-dir] )) && local -x GIT_DIR=${(e)opt_args[--git-dir]}
+        (( $+opt_args[--work-tree] )) && local -x GIT_WORK_TREE=${(e)opt_args[--work-tree]}
        if ! _call_function ret _git-$words[1]; then
          if zstyle -T :completion:$curcontext: use-fallback; then
            _default && ret=0
```

It applies clearly to `zsh 5.4.1` but it didn't work form me,YMMV.

I'll update this answer as the issue is being worked on.

EDIT:

With the above patch it does work, but where you put `add` is important - it has to be at the end:

```
git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME/ add
```

One more thing worth noticing - its somewhat slow.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the patch isn't working for me. I still get "not a git repository", even when taking care to put `add` at the end. I'll keep an eye on the mailing list, though, and hope that the issue gets satisfactorily resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The lastest (2018-04-20) official git completion works well.

https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion

To install,

```
mkdir -p ~/.zsh && cd $_
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

# The default behavior for 'git <TAB><TAB>' is to show a 10+ lines 'common commands' list.
# I prefer a full list.
# Better way to modify?
sed -i.bak '/^__git_zsh_cmd_common/,/{/ s/{/{\n\treturn/' _git

# add zshrc settings
vi ~/.zshrc
  fpath=(~/.zsh $fpath)
  # the next two lines are not needed if using oh-my-zsh
  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
```

PS,

My previous answer is about oh-my-zsh's plugin gitfast. But it has bugs, and it's very outdated.

Comment: To make this work, I had to rename `git-completion.zsh` to `_git` and add `zstyle ':completion:*:*:git:*' script ~/.zsh/git-completion.bash`, as per comment at the top of `git-completion.zsh'.

Comment: Also, do not use `master` branch. Instead, make sure you get the version of the script that matches your git version. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327817/git-completion-bash-producing-error-on-macos-sierra-10-12-6 for example of what might go wrong.