# Zsh autocompletion for git bare repos

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

This is the completion code in my `.zshrc`:

```bash
autoload -U compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zmodload zsh/complist
compinit
_comp_options+=(globdots)       # Include hidden files.
```

I've been having a problem with the autocompletion when i use an alias:
`config='/usr/bin/git --git-dir=$HOME/.local/share/dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME'`

This problem has been discussed and explained before (please check them they explain the problem better than i can) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550559/zsh-file-autocompletion-with-bare-git-repo) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350797/zsh-git-filename-completion-with-git-dir-work-tree-not-a-git-repo), and the only reason that I'm mentioning this even though it's been discussed is because none of the solution work, and because there's these line of  changes to the `_git` completion script that weren't there before:

```bash
        (( $+opt_args[--git-dir] )) && local -x GIT_DIR=${(Q)${~opt_args[--git-dir]}}
        (( $+opt_args[--work-tree] )) && local -x GIT_WORK_TREE=${(Q)${~opt_args[--work-tree]}}
```

These lines made the alias function but in one case only if the alias is written like i posted above it doesn't work but if the `$HOME` variables were replaced with `~` it works perfectly as it should the only problem is that if i do make that replacement the alias wouldn't work anymore and gives this error: `fatal: not a git repository: '~/.local/share/dotfiles'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating a bit I found out that it's a problem with the expansion of the `$HOME` variable, but the solution suggested [here](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2023/msg00282.html) works perfectly, I just replaced `--work-tree=$HOME` with `--work-tree ~` and it worked.

Comment: Nice :-) However please see the guidelines on [writing a good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help). You should present the entire solution in your answer to preserve it. If your link target disappears for whatever reason your answer becomes a lot less helpful.